# Generic method TypeParameter determining

Tags: java, generics

Conssider the following simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    List<Integer> li = createList();//ok, this mean that ArrayList<Integer> was returned
    List<Double> ld = createList();//ok, ArrayList<Double> was returned
}

public static <T> List<T> createList()
{
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

What is the algorithm of determining suitable type parameter in generic method? It would be good if you provide a referece to `JLS`.

Comment: sorry, you want to know the internals used by the language to make T work?

Comment: @Leo I am not interested in implementation details. I want to understand formal algorithm, if any, defined in JLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). The Java compiler takes a look at *target types* to infer the type parameters when invoking a generic method. In general, the target type of an expression "is the data type that the Java compiler expects depending on where the expression appears". So in your case you have:

```
List<Integer> li = createList();
```

Here, the target type is `List<Integer>`, with the generic parameter being `Integer`. Since the `createList` method has a return value of type `List<T>`, the compiler can infer that the generic type-argument `T` must be `Integer`. You can make this more explicit by using a type witness as well:

```
List<Integer> li = MyClass.<Integer>createList();
```

The actual algorithm is pretty involved and the JLS goes over it in [section 15.12.2.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7).

Comment: Very interesting. But what about if the target type is _Wildcard type_? What type is inferring in that case?

Comment: Do you mean if you have `List<?> li = createList();`?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: I assume it will do the same thing. It will return an `ArrayList<?>` instance.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It will infer the wildcard's bound for the type argument. For example `List<?> li = createList()` infers `Object`, and `List<? extends Number> li = createList()` and `List<? super Number> li = createList()` infer `Number`. Note that since the wildcard "gives up" type information, it doesn't really matter and the compiler just picks something valid.

Comment: @PaulBellora Are you sure that `List<?>` will infer `Object`? `List<?>` is not the same as `List<Object>`. Or am I just misunderstanding your comment? :)

Comment: @VivinPaliath `List<Object>` is assignable to `List<?>`, which is all that matters.

Comment: @PaulBellora _It will infer the wildcard's bound for the type argument._ Could you give a reference where it is specified?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Sure, I'll try to hunt through [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) later today. I can't remember the exact section of the top of my head. I hope it's at least clear why the inferred type doesn't matter, as long as it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JLS chapter on type inferring for generics:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7